# SQL query to get reserved words used in postgres sql db

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a SQL query that returns all the reserved words used in PostgreSQL database.

Comment: the query shoul return all the key words present in this doc https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Postgres provides the set-returning function `pg_get_keywords()` for that:

```
select *
from pg_get_keywords()
```

The columns of the result are documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#id-1.5.8.32.19.2.2.10.1.1.1)